# How can I verify a change in remote GitHub server ssh fingerprint?

Tags: ssh, git

When I try to clone a project from our work github server, I am seeing this error. Earlier today this was no problem, but this afternoon it suddenly started happening.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:<fingerprint>.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/<myname>/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/<myname>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
ECDSA host key for github.companysite.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
```

I even tried generating a fresh key pair, but that didn't solve it. The thing is, I have no way of knowing if the servers for our github instance changed and this is a legitimate new fingerprint or if it's an attack. I do have access to the web version of github for our company. Is there some way that I can check the server's fingerprint through the web page and compare to the one I'm receiving before I copy it into that trusted hosts file?

Edit for clarification: this is a private github instance for my company, not public github.

Comment: Is contacting your system administrator not an option?

Comment: Finding my system administrator is a last resort. It's going to be an act of congress to find out who that even is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I even tried generating a fresh key pair, but that didn't solve it.

The message is not talking about your key pair. It's talking about the *server's* key pair. (And the server's key pair changing is literally what *causes* the message, it can't possibly solve it.)

> Is there some way that I can check the server's fingerprint through the web page and compare to the one I'm receiving before I copy it into that trusted hosts file?

I couldn't find any documentation indicating that GitHub Enterprise has such a web page. I did however find [official docs](https://enterprise.github.com/releases/2.3.21/notes) indicating that it *did not* have such a web page in 2016 (2.3.x–2.7.x), according to this sentence:

"We strongly recommend publishing your GitHub Enterprise appliance's SSH host key fingerprints in a location that is accessible to all your end-users." which implies that it was entirely the sysadmin's responsibility to create such a web page.

Since GitHub.com still does not have an integrated SSH fingerprint list (only a manually updated article in the "help" section), I wouldn't expect GitHub Enterprise to have improved in that regard either.

So if your sysadmin has not created such a web page nor announced a hostkey change, you don't have many options left:

- You can try to rule out network-based MITM attacks by trying several different paths and comparing the fingerprints (in case there is a MITM on just one path) – e.g. assuming the server is globally accessible, first connect directly, then connect through a commercial VPN provider, then connect through your company's internal VPN (if any), then compare the results. If they're all identical, it's probably a legitimate fingerprint.
- You can ignore the change and connect anyway. If you are connecting within the company's own LAN, chances of a MITM attack aren't that high. (When you connect to the web site, does it have a valid TLS certificate? Or did it stop being valid at the same time the SSH hostkeys changed? Or did it never have a valid cert in the first place? This can serve as an indicator of MITM attack vs sysadmin incompetence.)
- `Please contact your system administrator.`